# Алгоритм вывода простых чисел

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, математика

Задан целочисленный массив размерности N. Если среди элементов массива есть простые числа, то вывести их номера.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с алгоритмом задачи. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Написал пример на C#, надеюсь алгоритм вы разберете сами.

Comment: уверен вы и сами сможете написать простенькую программку: для каждого элемента массива проверяем не делится ли он на следующие числа:  

`2 3 5 7 9 11 ... i-1`
(начинаем с 2-йки, при первом проходе увиличиваем на 1 потом каждый раз на 2)

если остаток деления равен нулю значит число не простое.

Comment: дополнение к предыдущему комменту: врехняя граница цикла  `(i/2) + 1` вместо `i - 1`

Answer (score 6):

Подход в лоб - это проход вдоль массива и проверка каждого элемента с помощью [решета Эратосфена](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Другой подход - это предварительное определение максимального элемента в массиве, отбор решетом простых чисел вплоть до максимального, затем проход по массиву и сопоставление с отобранными простыми числами.

Comment: Эратосфен в данном случае совсем плохо. Какого размера считать решето, зная лишь величину проверяемого числа ? 

IMHO, если эти числа многократно не повторяются, то достаточно проверять в цикле делимость на нечетные до корня из проверяемого числа.

Comment: Это как? Для каждого элемента получать последовательно все простые числа, меньше его, и сравнивать? Или в начале получить массив простых чисел < max и каждый элемент искать в массиве? Зачем это надо?

Comment: Нет, искать простые не надо. **Каждое** число делим на нечетные. Если не разделилось (до sqrt) то оно простое.

Если массив очень длинный (или известно, что в нем много простых), то можно конечно по ходу строить хэш из уже найденных в этом массиве простых чисел.

Comment: @avp, Ни, я свое замечание автору ответа адресовал.

Comment: Каждое число делим на нечетные. Если не разделилось (до sqrt) то оно простое...
Уважаемый @avp, а число 2^n? Так что, делим на нечетные и на 2.

Comment: Зачем делить на 2 ??? 

В самом начале, естественно, проверяем на равенство 1 или 2 (если равно, то простое). Потом смотрим, четное или нет (**if (x&1 == 0) goto NotPrime;**) Потом делим (в смысле проверяем остаток от деления) на нечетные. 

В каком месте делить на 2 ???

Кстати, не знаю 0 и отрицательные это не простые ? С ними тоже надо что-то делать.

Comment: @avp, потому что определение простого числа звучит, как: "Просто́е число́ — это натуральное число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя: единицу и самого себя". И формально, в начале цикла вы не знаете, является ли число 2 простым или нет. Как то так. Хотя, конечно, можно упростить алгоритм :).

Comment: @Olter, четность - это и есть свойство числа делиться на 2 без остатка. По этому зная четность числа мы знаем делится оно на 2 или нет.

Comment: В практических целях решето Эратосфена конечно употреблять не стоит. Стоит держать предвычисленную таблицу простых до какой то размерности, а числа большие проверяются недетерминированными методами, напрмер тест Рабина-Миллера

Answer (score 1):

Вот например код на C#:

```
void prime_num(long num)
{

for (long i = 0; i <= num; i++)
{
    bool isPrime = true; // Move initialization to here
    for (long j = 2; j < i; j++) // you actually only need to check up to sqrt(i)
    {
        if (i % j == 0) // you don't need the first condition
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ( "Prime:" + i );
    }
}
}
```

Взято со StackOverflow. [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510124/program-to-find-prime-numbers)

Грубо говоря, идет проверка, делится ли нужное вам число без остатка на возможные делители.

Comment: На **четные** зачем делить ? Раз StackOverflow, значит все OK ?

Answer (score 1):

Задача нетривиальная и какой способ ни приведи все равно будет плохим - все будет упираться в вычислительную мощность. Мне кажется наиболее оптимальный способ это найти максимальное число в массиве - скажем NMax далее взять из общеизвестного источника (например [такого](http://www.mathsisfun.com/prime_numbers.html)) массив простых числе меньше Nmax - обозначим их как P1... PK. Далее тупо начинаем перебор всех Ni деля их на P1...PK которые меньше Ni.

В смысле трудоемкости это очевидно менее затратно, чем решето Эратосфена - хотя есть проблема связанная с тем, что если Nmax будет очень большим - больше чем известное целое число, то метод провалится

Comment: Если уж брать (или вычислять) все эти простые, то **делить** для проверки ничего **не надо** ! Достаточно искать среди уже найденных простых.

Comment: Точно! Сам не сообразил :)

Comment: Спасибо всем, уже выполнил это :)